# Custom columns doesn't appear in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

Hi i have a 'tour' custom post types and when i add a custom column at this post type there is not any custom column at tour post type
my code is here

```
function tour_price_col( $column, $post_id){
switch ( $column ) {
    case 'price':
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tour-price', true );
        break;
    case 'test':
        echo "salam";
        break;
   }
}
add_action('manage_tour_posts_custom_column', 'tour_price_col', 10 ,2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to declare/register the new columns:

```
add_filter( 'manage_tour_posts_columns', 'cyb_add_new_columns' );
function cyb_add_new_columns() {
        $columns['price'] = __('Price column title', 'cyb-textdomain' );
        $columns['test']  = __('Test column title', 'cyb-textdomain' );
        return $columns;
}
```

Then, you can print the content of the column for each post:

```
add_action('manage_tour_posts_custom_column', 'tour_price_col', 10 ,2);
function tour_price_col( $column, $post_id){
  switch ( $column ) {
    case 'price':
        echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tour-price', true );
        break;
    case 'test':
        echo "salam";
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: How can i rearrange columns in table?

Comment: You need to insert the new elements in the `$columns` array in the position you desire. There are plenty of examples in Stackoverflow. For example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-arrays-at-specific-position), this one or this one.